# How to disable GNOME session lock on a VM? Privacy is already Off, Blank Screen on power saving: Never. But a Windows locking still causes its locking

Tags: gnome

I've a trouble some *Debian 10* VM running under *Windows*.

For a reason, it often freezes when re-entering a GNOME session.

Finding the root cause is difficult, and for yet I want to avoid facing the event causing the trouble, while I can't correct it.

From the *Settings*, in *Activities* Menu, I've turned off :

- Privacy Screen Lock
- Power -> Power Saving -> Screen Blank

I've also executed a:

```bash
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

However, if Windows locks its session (and I can't avoid it), at it's unlocking, I find my *Debian 10* VM locked too. And then, and I have a chance to face my issue.

Are there others commands I can use to disable entirely the lock process of GNOME?
I believe I might miss something, because the *Cafeine* extension (I doesn't use) is able to prevent *GNOME* from closing session.